# Can you tip brahmin in New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-3, fallout-new-vegas

Apparently you could tip brahmin in Fallout 3. This is one of those few things in Fallout 3 I never thought of, and thus never tried.

Rather than loading up Fallout 3 *just* to go brahmin-tipping, I'm wondering if you can do that in New Vegas as well, as they're built on the same tech?

Comment: I would imagine so...although I'll bet active NV players should easily be able to find out.

Comment: Haven't found any brahmin yet. :)

Comment: Yet to find a Brahmin to test on, but you cannot tip Bighorns.

Comment: @LessPop: I figured as much, since everyone warned that they get a bit ... testy ... when you get too close. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, but what does "tip" mean in this context?

Comment: Think cow-tipping. Brahmin, in the Fallout world, are the mutated (typically two-headed) descendants of cows. The name comes from the Indian (continent, not Native American) word for the sacred cow.

Comment: I also don't know what cow-tipping is -- but I'll look it up

Comment: @Juan: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cow_tipping Purported hobby of drunk midwesterners since time immemorial.

Comment: ohhh... poor Brahmin!

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz As a southerner I can confirm it isn't limited to the midwest...sadly.

Comment: @rapida: The use of the word 'purported' is important here. As the Wikipedia link points out, actual cow tipping is, for the most part, physically impossible.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz But it is 'purported' in most US rural areas.  Might have something to do with "drunk".

Comment: This is considered a southern thing, not a midwestern thing.

Comment: Convenience link for F3 brahmin tipping: http://www.gamespot.com/ps3/rpg/fallout3/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-46307397&pid=939932

Comment: Turns out this is referenced in-game. The first time you speak to __Minor spoiler coming__ Keller in Miguel's Pawn Shop, one of the dialog options is "Brahmin tipping is a cherished pastime."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Confirmed, Brahmin tipping is in.

You can test for yourself at the Mojave Outpost, west of Nipton, Southwest of Primm.