# How do you tip brahmin?

Tags: fallout-3, fallout-new-vegas

Now that we've established that [you can tip brahmin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/9425/58) in New Vegas (as well as Fallout 3), how does one actually go about tipping a brahmin?

Comment: The answer to this question belongs in the other question; this should be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Brahmin_tipping).

> #### For Fallout 3 (and New Vegas)
>
> By crouching near a brahmin and pressing the activate button you will push the brahmin over, causing it to go into a ragdoll state and getting back on its feet in a couple of seconds. You will not lose any Karma for doing this, nor will anyone or anything become hostile. Be warned that repeating this action may cause the brahmin to die. Even after it dies, no one becomes hostile and you do not lose Karma. You may also loot the body for brahmin steak.

Comment: I actually looked it up yesterday to try to understand your other question (and I guess it works the same as F3 because it runs on the same engine)